# PhpStorm - Git last update info in project tree

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, phpstorm

How can I remove these bits of information from project tree? It's fine to know when I did the last push but the tree become very hard to read. How can I remove that or is here any better settings?

I'm using PhpStorm.

[image]

Comment: That info looks to be the last commit affecting each file, rather than the last "push". I'm guessing that once you have multiple commits you'll likely prefer to see it there, rather than wishing to hide it. The commit ID hash is generally useful to have quick access to in Git. (I have no idea if you *can* hide it though...)

Comment: [This looks similar](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/project-tool-window.html#show-filesize-timestamp) to what you are seeing. Maybe there are other options in "View | Appearance | Details in Tree Views" for showing file size and date instead?

Comment: What custom (not bundled by default) plugins do you have? Could be one of them (e.g. Git Toolbox)